# How to specify browser language in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer, browser-testing

I would like to launch a Google Chrome browser with language Spanish `es` using Puppeteer.

I've tried `puppeteer.launch(args:['--lang=es',...],...)` but it didn't work.

I've tried passing the environment variable `LANGUAGE=es mocha puppeteer-test.js` but it didn't work.

I've tried using the `userDataDir` option and passing a folder with a `Preferences` file a `{ "intl": { "accept_languages": "es" } }` but the browser Settings - Languages still don't show Spanish and neither does `window.navigator.languages` neither `window.navigator.language`

I'm using
Puppeteer 0.11.0
Node 8.4.0
NPM 5.2.0
macOS El Capitan 10.11.6
MacBook Pro Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015

Comment: Is passing language arguments works when starting Chromium browser from the terminal?

Comment: I have the same problem, "window.navigator" is undefined in Puppeteer's headless Chromium, even when using the --lang switch.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There are several ways to change locale, you can try all of them to find what works for you,

## Use Args when launching

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ['--lang=bn-BD,bn']
});
```

## Send the language as Header

```
await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    'Accept-Language': 'bn'
});
```

## Forcefully set the language

```
// Set the language forcefully on javascript
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, "language", {
        get: function() {
            return "bn-BD";
        }
    });
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, "languages", {
        get: function() {
            return ["bn-BD", "bn"];
        }
    });
});
```

For the sake of testing, I'll test this in multiple languages, including `es`, and here is the result.

### Google search:

[image: es]
[image: bn]

### BrowserLeaks:

[image]

Comment: Mind you, that `args` solution doesnt work on mac os

Comment: Is there another way for mac OS X?

Comment: At [Chromium issue 755338](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=755338#c13) they write that setting environment variable `LANG` should work as well on Linux. Nothing like that for Windows though, it seems...

Comment: Neither of them worked for me

Answer (score 8):

There's an error in Md-Abu-Taher's answer.

The response to `navigator.language` should return a string, not an array. Try it in your own browser console.

The code snippet should be:

```
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, "language", {
        get: function() {
            return "en-GB";
        }
    });
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, "languages", {
        get: function() {
            return ["en-GB", "en"];
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

On Chrome Linux, you can do

```
puppeteer.launch({ ...yourParams, env: { LANGUAGE: "fr_FR" } })
```

I don't know for the others OS/browsers ...

Comment: funny enough my puppeteer fails to start on linux when i tried adding this env variable... super weird

"Error: Failed to launch the browser process! undefined"