# Change locale on the fly after browser initialization with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless, server-side-rendering

With puppeteer, can we change the lang after we specified it during the browser launching ?

In my code below, I'm specifying the lang with the `--lang` parameter for chrome headless but I would love to know if later in my code we can change, on the fly, the language...

Here's how I set the lang in a first time :

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [`--lang=${lang}`]
});

... some stuff here
// then change the lang here
```

Then after in my code I've been tried to change like that (but it's doesn't work) :

```
await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    'Accept-Language': lang
});
```

I found this solution here : [How to specify browser language in Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46908636/how-to-specify-browser-language-in-puppeteer)

Also I have tried to create a wsEndpoint (it's what I want to do in fact, like the Ebidel's article : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/articles/ssr#reuseinstance) and to change the lang like that :

```
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
   browserWSEndpoint,
   args: [`--lang=${lang}`]
});
```

...but it's still doesn't work.

Have you an idea how to do that ? I've found few topics about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally there's no way to do that for the moment.