# Puppeteer - Hotel website will not load for webscraping

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

**Background:** I am trying to webscrape a hotel website ([normal hyatt](https://www.hyatt.com/) and that website loads normally when I go to that URL (as expected).

[image: normal]

[image: not loading]

**Problem:** However, when I use Puppeteer to access that website, the headless mode Chromium is blank for the exact link.

Code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const fs = require('fs/promises');

let browser;
async function hyattScan() {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    // * select `false` if you want to run non-headless mode for testing
    headless: false
  });
  page = await browser.newPage();

  // Set the user agent to mimic Firefox
  const ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0';
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.setViewport({ width: 2000, height: 1500 });


  await page.goto('https://www.hyatt.com/', { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });

  await page.waitForTimeout(15000);
  
}


// * Call the main function
(async () => {
    console.log('Starting the Hyatt scraper program...');
    await hyattScan()
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
      .finally(() => browser?.close());
 
  })();
```

Comment: Are you sure the website is not detecting you are not a "real" browser?

Comment: If they did their homework, they will have anti-scraping measures in place.

Comment: fingerprinting... see [Puppeteer loads blank page with 429 when accessing URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56500643/puppeteer-loads-blank-page-with-429-when-accessing-url)

Comment: I've tried adding 
`
await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
});
`
but that didn't work either

Comment: Your script is good but the website protection is better :D Looks like this website is protected by Kasada https://www.kasada.io/ same service that protects the Nike website. Maybe you find something useful in this article https://www.nullpt.rs/devirtualizing-nike-vm-1